# Multivariate multiple regression assumptions, how to interpret findings SPSS?

Tags: regression, spss, multivariate-analysis

I am trying to perform a multivariate multiple regression in SPSS. I have 5 independent variables and 4 dependent variables. I know it can be done in SPSS using the GLM-multivariate option. My questions are:

1. What are the assumptions for a multivariate multiple regression?
2. How do I interpret the findings (how are these findings different from the findings of a regular multiple regression)?

I am using this link as a [reference](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mplus/dae/mvreg.htm/) (however, this is MPlus and I need the information for SPSS).

Any ideas, code, or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CV! I've edited your title to reflect your question content, please feel free to correct it if I've erred.

Comment: The terminology _multiple_ regression is fine but increasingly it seems unnecessary to stress _multiple_ as it's the same idea really and having multiple predictors is utterly routine. Conversely, the terminology _multivariate_ regression seems, if not absolutely needed, then at least helpful as flagging a less common variant. I've not previously seen the composite form _multivariate multiple regression_ and (although that composite puts all the cards on the table) I would commend just _multivariate regression_ as the term for what you are doing.

Comment: There's a nice article in the AJPH that says the word multivariate should not be synonymous with multivariable. (I think that for Americans it is, more than Europeans).

Answer (score 1):

Multivariate multiple regression tests multiple IV's on Multiple DV's simultaneously, where multiple linear regression can test multiple IV's on a single DV.  This is why multivariate is coupled with multiple regression.  The assumptions are the same for multiple regression as multivariate multiple regression.

Comment: This is fine as a start but says absolutely nothing about what the assumptions are.